# Можно ли класс создать в интерфейсе

Tags: java, классы, интерфейс

Понимаю абсурдность моего вопроса, просто хочу убедится в отсутствии этой реализации. Но с другой стороны, почему нельзя добавить внутренний класс в интерфейсе, как статический метод? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понятно почему вопрос абсурдный. Ответ можно объявить класс внутри [интерфейса](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Can-we-define-a-class-inside-a-Java-interface).

```
interface Library {
   void issueBook(Book b);
   void retrieveBook(Book b);
   public class Book {
      int bookId;
      String bookName;
      int issueDate;
      int returnDate;
   }
}
public class Sample implements Library {
   public void issueBook(Book b) {
      System.out.println("Book Issued");
   }
   public void retrieveBook(Book b) {
      System.out.println("Book Retrieved");
   }
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Sample obj = new Sample();
      obj.issueBook(new Library.Book());
      obj.retrieveBook(new Library.Book());
   }
}
```

Comment: Мне казалось это бесполезной вещью. А для чего это может пригодится?

Comment: @Альберт По мне я никогда не применял. Пример конечно можно придумать, но завязываться на конкретный класс тем самым делать связь сильной противоречит принципу DI. Так что возможность создать класс есть, только вот использовать вместо Book интерфейс намного правильнее.